# How can I get the previous page using Cookies and Local storage on refreshing the web browser

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the previous page using Cookies and Local storage on refreshing the web browser. PLEASE suggest me with simple example or refer with any link...

Comment: What do you mean by "previous action" exactly? Please add more detail on what you want to achieve.

Comment: You'll have to store the actions, to begin with, as cookies and localStorage aren't written automatically.